# Get the index of selected value from input dropdownlist / Differentiate between dublicate values

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently working on implementing a search bar which gets dynamically filled with names depending on the user input. Each name has a corresponding id. I can request the id as well as the name from a database.
I'm allowing duplicate name entries into the database.
To simplify things let's just say the database has the values:

`{name:"Name1",id:1},
{name:"Name2",id:2},
{name:"Name2",id:3}`

In the input field when typing in "Name" it would then show in the dropdownlist the values Name1,Name2,Name2.
Let's say the user selects the second entry("Name2") how could I then tell if he selected the value of "Name2" with the corresponding id: 2 or the one with the id of 3?

One idea would be to somehow get the index of the selected value but I dont' know how to do that.

https://jsfiddle.net/zka067y3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this following jQuery script and HTML code.

```js
$('#inputValues').on('input',function(){
    var g=$('input[type="text"]').val();  
  var id = $('#playernames').find('option').filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ) === g; }).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div> 
  <input id="inputValues" type="text" name="userName" list="playernames">
  <datalist id="playernames">
  <option value="Name1" id="1">Name1</option>
  <option value="Name2" id="2">Name2</option>
  <option value="Name2" id="3">Name2</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery sure is useful!
I had to add an if statement so that id != undefined but other than that it's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I just realized it doesn't work.It automatically chooses the first id in the datalist even when I'm selecting the third value. So choosing the options with id 3 returns 2.